# How to get width and height of the image?

Tags: android

HI,

I want to get width and height of the image which i was stored in the drawable folder.
Is this possible, if so please let me know ?

Comment: This is very good answer, i used this answer to set same with message status ImageView[one checked icon, two checked icon] : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655534/android-obtaining-image-size-from-its-resource-id

Answer (score 62, accepted):

try

```
BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
int height=bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
int width=bd.getBitmap().getWidth();
```

Comment: I would prefer to do this without casts, by using Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth/Height().

Comment: using the above code, getting two-third of the original size. For e.g-  an image has  644 X 550 dimension; but am getting- 429 X 367 from code. What may be the issue?

Comment: do you have multiple density folders? hdpi and mdpi? sounds like BitmapDrawable is getting confused with which one to pick. set the right density in the Options, like http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Comment: getDrawable method is deprected . which method used instead of "getDrawable" method

Comment: The non-deprecated version of getDrawable is ResourcesCompat.getDrawable, which supports themes. If you don't need a theme, just pass null into it (docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html).

Answer (score 15):

I have follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880376/how-to-get-height-and-width-of-a-image-used-in-android) link :-

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage);
int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
```

Comment: this is more applicable for me, because gives you the size of View independent of  weather it is shown on screen or not!