# How to get the size of an image in Android?

Tags: android, image, image-size

I'm able to get the height and width of an image. But is there a method to retrieve the size (in bytes or kb or mb) for an image stored in the phone?

Comment: File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.file");
long length = file.length();

Comment: Before this, how you were getting the height and width of the image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8880528/867591

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. This is how I finally resolved it:

```
 Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);


     Bitmap bitmap = bitmapOrg;
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);   
     byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray(); 
     long lengthbmp = imageInByte.length;
```

Appreciate your time and answers :)

Comment: Goon Answer. lengthbmp is in byte. lengthbmp/1024.0 is in KB. lengthbmp/1024.0/1024.0 is in MB.

Comment: How to get before compress and after compress?

Comment: Before compressing you can use `bitmap.getByteCount()`. Bear in mind that the "compressed" version is a JPEG, so if you compare both sizes you're not necessarily comparing apples to apples.

Answer (score 11):

You just need to create a new `File` object such as...

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/file.png";
File file = new File(filepath);
long length = file.length();
```

Comment: this gives the size of the file, not the image.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your talking about a bitmap (and NOT an ImageView), there is a method [Bitmap.getByteCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getByteCount%28%29).

Comment: @mehmet Yes, but as of two years ago, when this was posted, it worked. I'll update when I get a chance.

Comment: use [android.support.v4.graphics.BitmapCompat#getAllocationByteCount](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/BitmapCompat.html#getAllocationByteCount%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) for      compatibility.

Answer (score 7):

```
 File file = new File("/sdcard/imageName.jpeg");
 long length = file.length();
 length = length/1024;
 System.out.println("File Path : " + file.getPath() + ", File size : " + length +" KB");
```

Answer (score 4):

This returns the true size that is match in computers when you see file details with right click.

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/my_video.mp4");
long length = file.length() / 1024; // Size in KB
```