# Find out the size of stored image file

Tags: android, image

Is there a way I can determine the size of an image (jpg) file in Android? I want to know the size of the image and if that's 0KB then delete it. Many thanks.

Comment: @DTH I have gone though this link but it doesn't return the correct size. The size of my file is 0KB and this code in the link you provided returns 27.

Comment: Wonder if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316986/how-to-get-the-size-of-an-image-in-android

Comment: @DTH thanks a lot. You are right and it is working fine :)

Comment: @DeboshresthaDe thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use File.length()

Will return 0 if:

- if the file exists but contained zero bytes.
- if the file does not exist
- if the file is some OS-specific special file.

Also be advised that a file with the size of 0KB will not necessarily return 0 when calling file.length if the file is less than 1KB (for example 27 bytes).