# how to set a imageview height based on its width, calculate it programatically

Tags: android, imageview

for example:
I am having a imageView width fixed of 600dp and height has to be calculated based on the given image height and fixed width(600dp). it should be in such a way that it matches the width not much big not small.

Comment: first you must get image width and height. then calculate ratio and apply the ratio into your fixed dimension

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880376/how-to-get-height-and-width-of-a-image-used-in-android Using this links you can find image height and width.