# How to draw a bitmap with my own dimensions?

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to draw a bit my according to dimensions that I will set later on. But the only method Im familliar with is the following one:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(test, canvas.getWidth()/2 - test.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2  - test.getHeight()/2, null);
```

which only draw the bitmap accordign to the image dimension, so my question is, is there another method to draw a bitmap with different dimension or just a way to change it?

Thanks!

Comment: [Use this one:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346412/draw-bitmap-on-canvas-with-original-dimension

Comment: If you read the documentation you can see 7 methods for canvas.drawBitmap: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: yeah i saw the other methods, but which 1 do i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to resize bitmap with your choice dimensions:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) {

   final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

   options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    return bmp;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
 return inSampleSize;
 }
```